# Why is it easier to put one's arm on table for lifting a box?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life, torque

Why is it easier to put your elbow on the table to lift a box compared to just lifting it, hand in the air? Is it like some kind of torque or fulcrum and lever?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using different muscles, so the scenarios are not directly comparable.

But your premise that it is easier with the elbow on the table is not necessarily correct. It really depends on *how* you lift it when not touching the table.

- If you hold your arm **vertically** and perform a deadlift (grab the object from above and lift straight up without bending the arm), then you use muscles in your legs, especially the thighs, which are - most probably - massively stronger than your arms. No muscles in your arms are stressed because it is the bones that carry the entire weight. This will always be way easier than any arm-vs-table configuration I can think of.
- If you on the other hand hold your arm **horizontally**, then the object's weight will cause a torque about your shoulder levered by your arm's length. It requires triceps strength to counteract this torque in order to hold the object off of the table in this manner. This is tough. Even holding a milk cartridge like this for more than a minute or so can be a challenge.

The torque $\tau$ exerted by the object when held in such a manner is: $$\tau = Fd$$
with $F$ being the force (that would be the weight of the object) and $d$ the perpendicular distance to the hinge (to the shoulder in this case, and $d$ will always be the horizontal distance to the shoulder since the weight pulls vertically). When such a torque is exerted by the object, some muscle in your body must balance it out with a counter-torque.

- If you hold your arm at **any other angle** than horizontally or vertically, then bones carry some weight and muscles only must make up for a smaller fraction of the torque (plus the torque will be smaller, since the perpendicular lever distance is shortened). The horizontally straight-arm case would be the toughest.

And now to the elbow-on-table scenario:

- When placing the **elbow on the table**, you move the hinge point from shoulder to elbow. The torque exerted by the object will be smaller due to this smaller lever distance. At the same time, you are now using a different set of muscles, your biceps, which usually is stronger than the triceps.

All in all, the elbow-on-table scenario requires less torque than the horizontal straight-arm scenario. If not horizontal, then the more angled your straight arm is, the small the necessary torque will be, and at a certain angle it will be just as light (in terms of torque) as the elbow-on-table case. But, with all that being said about the torque, it is very difficult to compare the different scenarios in terms of which is easier and which is tougher, because different muscles are used in different configurations.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was actually wondering how it would be like to make a robot arm move subjects with less energy, so I wasn't worrying about muscles. Do you think it would be easier to pick up objects with elbow on a table (and remaining on the table, moving with a wheel instead of lifting the elbow off the table) if the elbow and arm and shoulder was of a robot?

Comment: @parvin The closer the hinge point is to the lifting (the smaller the perpendicular distance is), the better. That is all that is important.